# What does the symbol (A = R × R) means and are equivalent classes countless on some specific set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let A be the points in the plane ($A = R × R$).  Two points are equivalent if they are equal distances from the origin. So($x,y$)~($w,z$) if $x^2$ + $y^2$ = $w^2$ + $z^2$.I need to show the relation is an equivalence and find the equivalence classes.

Now I am confused about what is A. What the mean that A is a point and $A = R × R$? IS this means a point such as $(4,9)$ in the form of ($a\times a$,$b\times b$)?

Another question is if the equivalence classes are countless since  $A\in R$?

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is the set of real numbers.  $\times$ is the cartesian product.  $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ is then the set of pairs of real numbers... what you might otherwise know as the two-dimensional plane

Comment: Thank you a lot, I had a misunderstanding about the symbol before. @JMoravitz

Comment: So, can equivalence classes countless?

Comment: $(x,y)\sim (w,z) \iff x^2 + y^2= w^2 + z^2$; otherwise it makes no sense. In mathematics, even elementary, upper and lower case letters do not designate the same object. For example, at the very beginning of the study of elementary geometry, $d$ will designate a line while $D$ will designate a point.

Comment: For example,[(1,2)] = {(-1,2),(1,2),(1,-2),(-1,-2)}, [(1,3)] = {(-1,3),(1,3),(1,-3),(-1,-3)} These are equivalence classes for(1,2) and (1,3) There are countless pairs of real numbers. If this means there are countless equivalence classes countless?

Comment: Only four points on a circle. What an interesting geometry!

Comment: oops, I made a mistake again. Then how do I express this? should I write an equation to represent equivalence classes? Like[(a,b)] = {(c,d) | $a^2$+$b^2$=$c^2$+$d^2$}?@StéphaneJaouen

Comment: That is perfectly fine.  Yes, what you wrote is indeed the equivalence class of $(a,b)$.  Yes, there can be infinitely many (*including uncountably infinitely many*) different equivalence classes.  Yes, there can be infinitely many elements within an equivalence class.  Yes, that will be the case here for every equivalence class except for the equivalence class of $(0,0)$ who has just the single element.  Your equivalence classes here each geometrically represent the different possible circles who have the origin as their center.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have already struggled with this question for several hours because I can't find some good examples in the textbook. Now I understand. Thank you again. @JMoravitz